# JS Multiple Sticky Divs and Anchors

Tags: html, anchor, sticky

http://nickscarantino.ministryportfolio.com/ Is the website I'm working on.

My plan for it was to have a different "header" for each section (the navication on the top). I want those headers to stick to the top, and use anchors to scroll down the page. But the anchors end up jumping around the page.

For instance, when i click "history" it should scroll to the "history" anchor and keep that header at the top of the page. But sometimes when i click "history" (for instance- after clicking resume) it will scroll all the way to the top of the page, rather than where the history anchor is located.

How do i fix this?

Comment: I _think_ i fixed the problem myself. I set the anchors to have an absolute position. <a href="history" style="position:absolute; top:500px;"> as that is where the "#history" div is set at. I will include the JS code I'm using in another comment, maybe there is a better way to accomplish what i would like done.

Comment: `$(window).scroll(function (e) {
    $scrollTopDiff = 500 - $(this).scrollTop();
    
    $('#history').css({
        'top': ( $scrollTopDiff > 0 ? $scrollTopDiff : 0 ) + 'px'
    });
});

$(window).scroll(function (e) {
    $scrollTopDiff = 1500 - $(this).scrollTop();
    
    $('#resume').css({
        'top': ( $scrollTopDiff > 0 ? $scrollTopDiff : 0 ) + 'px'
    });
});
</script>

 <style>
 #resume{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top:500;
    width: 100%;
}
 #history {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top:1500;
    width: 100%;
}`

Comment: the divs are set up using:

`<div id="history" style="margin-left:-5px; width:105%; height:150px; z-index:56;background-image:url('http://nickscarantino.ministryportfolio.com/topbg.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size: 100% 150px; overflow:hidden; vertical-align:top;"> `